# EditText validation in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, ksoap

I developed a login form using MySQL database connection through SOAP web services. Here I validate my EditText(username,password)box. This is a basic question,but I can't develop the code for this. Help me please.

My code is:

```
Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View arg0) {
loginAction();

  }
 });
}

private void loginAction(){
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("password");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
           String status = response.toString();
           TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
           result.setText(response.toString());

           **if(status.equals("Success!"))
           {
               //   ADD  to save  and  read next time
                   String strUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
                   String strPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                   if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0)
                               {
                       //  showToast("Enter Your Name");
                     userName.setError( "username is required!" );
                   } else if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0)
                               {
                           //      showToast("Enter Your Password");
                     userPassword.setError( "password is required!" );
                   } else
                               {
                       if (chkRememberMe.isChecked())
                                       {
                           SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                           loginPreferences.edit().putString(USERNAME, strUserName).putString(PASSWORD, strPassword).commit();
                       } else
                                       {
                           SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                           loginPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
                                       }
           Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,HomePage.class);
              intent.putExtra("username",userName.getText().toString());
              startActivity(intent);
                               }
           }**
                   else
                      {
                       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                         startActivity(i);
                      }
                     }



              catch(Exception e){

              }
             }

      }
```

I wish that if I clicked the button, then the EditText would get validated first and then only move to the next Activity.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean variable **isValidated**. Check if the username or the password field is empty or not. If any one of them is empty, set isValidated to **"false"**. Otherwise, set isValidated to **"true"**.

Now, before starting your next activity check the value of isValidated. ***If it is "true", then start the new Intent*** ; otherwise do whatever you want to if it is not validated (value of isValidated will be false in that case).

```
    private void loginAction(){

            boolean isUserValidated = true;
            boolean isPasswordValidated = true;

                 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
                    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
                    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
                    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

                  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
                    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
                    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
                    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
                    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

                  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
                    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    passwordProp.setName("password");
                    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
                    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    try{
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                           String status = response.toString();
                           TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
                           result.setText(response.toString());

                           if(status.equals("Success!"))
                           {
                               //   ADD  to save  and  read next time
                                   String strUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
                                   String strPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                                   if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0)
                                               {
                                       //  showToast("Enter Your Name");
                                     userName.setError( "username is required!" );
            isUserValidated = false;
                                   }
if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0)
                                               {
                                           //      showToast("Enter Your Password");
            isPasswordValidated = false;
                                     userPassword.setError( "password is required!" );
                                   } 
if(isUserValidated = true && isPasswordValidated = true)
                                               {

                                       if (chkRememberMe.isChecked())
                                                       {
                                           SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                           loginPreferences.edit().putString(USERNAME, strUserName).putString(PASSWORD, strPassword).commit();
                                       } else
                                                       {
                                           SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                           loginPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
                                                       }
}

            if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
            {
                           Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,HomePage.class);
                              intent.putExtra("username",userName.getText().toString());
                              startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
        {
        \\ what ever you want to do if the data in the EditText is not validated.
        \\ Maybe restart the same intent ?    
    \\ Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);    startActivity(i);


        }

                                               }
                           }
                                   else
                                      {
                                       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                                         startActivity(i);
                                      }
                                     }



                              catch(Exception e){

                              }
                             }

                      }
```

Comment: hi swayam it is not helpful for me.if i entered username and empty password it is go to login page and not displayed error messages.if both boxes empty means it is displayed username error messages only not display password error messages.

Comment: Well, in that case declare two boolean values. isUserNameValidated and isPasswordValidated. And before moving to the next intent, check if both the values are true or not.

Comment: ya very nice idea.how is to do

Comment: how is to do if condition using AND method. if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0)
                                   {
                           //  showToast("Enter Your Name");
                      userName.setError( "username is required!" );
                       } else if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0)
                                   {
                               //      showToast("Enter Your Password");
                      userPassword.setError( "password is required!" );
                       } how is used both if condition using AND metho

Comment: What problem are you facing now ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14069/discussion-between-krishnaveni-and-swayam)

Comment: Hi your updated code is not worked....again same mistake only displayed.if both boxes empty means the error messages is displayed.but entered anyone and blank anyone means does not displayed error messages but goto login page..but i wish to need that time also displayed error messages and don't go to login page.